# why fs25r12w1t4 infineon module is burnt out when high current is paassed through it?

Tags: induction-motor, gate-driving, igbt, vfd

I am implementing a VFD for Induction motor drive. I have used fs25r12w1t4 Infineon IGBT module ( 1200v 25A) with gate driver 6ed003l06-f2. It always burnt out when I passed 2A current. What may the reasons? Picture of the PCB design is attached here.  Date resistance is 30 ohm. 
can you suggest me any other IGBT module that must be useful for VFD? and also gate driver. 
I connected load as an induction motor. for the test purpose, I started with low speed but after 15 minutes, all the system burnt out.

[image]
Schamatic of gate driver with IGBT module 
[image]
layout of PCB
[image]

Comment: Show us the schematic too.

Comment: In general, you need to be careful about the turn on/off of IGBTs, because that is where they burn most of their power. What is your switching frequency? Also, be sure that you are not leaving them both on and getting a shoot-through current.

Comment: my Switching frequency is 4K HZ . I  am using SPWM techniques. I have added deadtime for the IGBT to avoid shoot through. 2.5us is the deadtime .

Comment: It looks like you're missing the bootstrap doide going to VB1, is that true?

Comment: Dear @pscheidler, I am using Bootstrap diode. they are not showing in the figure .. they are connected below the gate driver.

Comment: There's not a lot of info here, so all I can suggest is to look at the signal going to your gates. If, for whatever reason, it is not fully turning on the gates, then you'll get a lot of resistive losses and things will explode. Your switching losses should be around 1-2W per device (=(Eon + Eoff)*fSw*2A/25A, see https://www.dynexsemi.com/assets/downloads/DNX_AN6156.pdf for details), which is not a lot, but you also don't have any heat sink. There could also be an unintended current spike due to your inductive load and low gate driver.

Comment: Remember to probe the high side gate appropriately! The high side gate is close you your DC bus voltage, even when the gate is off

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be for just one phase. Do you understand how single phase induction motors function? most of them will have Starting, or Starting and Running capacitors and the capacitor charging current will damage the IGBTs.